# [ERROR CoreDNSUnsupportedPlugins]: there are unsupported plugins in the CoreDNS Corefile when upgrading k8s cluster. What is unsupported?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to update a k8s cluster to 1.19.3, but when I try to upgrade the master it complains about unsupported plugins. I have looked at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/82889, but I didn't see the same plugin in the Corefile. This is the first time I have had to upgrade a cluster. This is my current cluster state: [image: Node list]

and corefile:

```
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          upstream 10.77.16.2 10.129.16.16 10.128.16.18
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . 10.77.16.2 10.129.16.16 10.128.16.18 {
          prefer_udp
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"Corefile":".:53 {\n    errors\n    health\n    ready\n    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {\n      pods insecure\n      upstream 10.77.16.2 10.129.16.16 10.128.16.18\n      fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa\n    }\n    prometheus :9153\n    forward . 10.77.16.2 10.129.16.16 10.128.16.18 {\n      prefer_udp\n    }\n    cache 30\n    loop\n    reload\n    loadbalance\n}\n"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"EnsureExists"},"name":"coredns","namespace":"kube-system"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2019-10-22T15:44:24Z"
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "3201"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: d2e3ba9a-f4e2-11e9-81f5-0050568f4e0e
```

describe nodes for w-1 shows failed to initialize csinode; error updating csinode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by the server could not find the requested resource as the message for kubelet not ready

Comment: Have you tried using `--ignore-preflight-errors=CoreDNSUnsupportedPlugins` as suggested in the github case?

Comment: I thought about, but being new to this and unaware of the root cause, I was hesitant as this was a production instance at the time.